# how to make all list items stretch to full width of a container

Tags: html, css

I' trying to create a nav that's responsive but I can't get then menu items to stretch itself relative to the container.

What's the most effective modern method of making all elements auto fit themselves full width of a container?

```css
nav {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  width: 700px;
}

ul {
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
}

ul li {
  padding: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">d</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">e</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">f</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: With responsiveness in mind I wouldn't use pixels when setting widths and heights, unless this is inside a media query

Answer (score 7):

I would use CSS tables as follows.

For `ul`, use `display: table` and zero out the margin and padding, and set width to 100%.

For `ul li`, use `display: table-cell`.

The table cells will adjust themselves to the width of the parent in a reasonable fashion taking into account the width of the link text/labels.

Note: I assumed that you want the links to be inline such that all the links fill up the width, as opposed to a single link taking up 100% of the width.  Otherwise, change `display: inline-block` to `display: block` for the `li` elements, but since that is too obvious, I assumed that you wanted a horizontal layout.

```css
nav {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  width: 700px;
}
ul {
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul li {
  padding: 25px;
  display: table-cell;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">d</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">e</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">f</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 5):

let's say that effective is in the eye of the beholder, but flexbox is quite modern:

```
nav { display: flex; border: solid 1px #000; width: 700px; }
ul { display: flex; flex-grow: 1; width: 100%; padding: 10px;
     list-style-type: none; }
ul li { flex-grow: 1; padding: 25px; margin: 10px;
        text-align: center; background: #000; color: #fff; }
```

see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4dxkk5wr/18/

and this resource: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

and have fun!

Answer (score 3):

If you really want the most modern solution, you could try flexbox layout: http://jsfiddle.net/4dxkk5wr/15/

```
ul { width: 100%; list-style-type: none; display: flex; padding: 0; }
ul li { width: 100%; padding: 25px; box-sizing: border-box; background: #000; color: #fff; flex-wrap: nowrap; }
```

Comment: +1 for flexbox mention, but I wonder if the most modern solution would leave out support for ie 8,9, and 10(if disregarding prefixes)

Comment: Yeah some older browsers would be left out for sure. But personally I do not care about them anymore unless a client explicitly demands support for them. Actually I absolutely hate this crappy MS stuff ... they kill progress and force us to stay on the same technological level as 10 years ago, it's ridiculous. So stop supporting this crap!

Answer (score 1):

Use **flexbox**! More [information](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Give the container the CSS:

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
```

and children: `flex: 1 0`

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/h7zqgr00/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4dxkk5wr/10/

You can use:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
width:100%;
```

in the li tag and set the padding to 0 on the ul.

Comment: I interpreted the question differently (the OP will clarify hopefully).  In your solution, you could also use `display: block` instead of `display: inline-block` for the `li` elements, would give basically the same results.

Answer (score 0):

**you can use this css**

```
nav {
  border: solid 1px black; 
  width: 100%; 
}
 ul { 
   width: 100%; 
   list-style-type: none; 
   width:100%;
   margin-left: -35px;
}
 ul li { 
   padding: 100px; 
   display: inline-block;
   background: #000;
   color: #fff;

}
```